# Why can't RSelenium find chromedriver when hosted as a job on Github Actions?

Tags: r, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, github-actions, rselenium

I have a script that uses RSelenium to scrape a dynamically generated website. It works locally on my Windows machine with Chrome installed.

However, putting it on Github Actions causes an error with finding the Chrome driver, presumably because it doesn't exist on the VM.

What do I need to change to enable my script to run?

The repo is located [here](https://github.com/aaronw22/ois-curve-tracker).

[Here](https://github.com/aaronw22/ois-curve-tracker/actions/runs/5861108219/job/15890575568) is an example of a failed job and the associated error message.

```
Run Rscript -e 'source("R/job.R", echo = TRUE)'

> library(data.table)

> library(rvest)

> library(RSelenium)

> Sys.setenv(TZ = "Australia/Sydney")

> binman::list_versions("chromedriver")
Error: Error: ~/Library/Application Support/binman_chromedriver app directory not found.
Execution halted
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```